# Enable scrolling after the video ends

Tags: javascript

I am adding a video intro into my project the process is:
Once video ends, Div hides and shows the hero section

But I want to disable the scrolling while the video is playing so that they can't scrub to the rest of the page. Here's my code so far, please forgive me I am a total newbie on this.

```
<div id="loginVideoLayer" class="loginvideoLayer">

    <video id="loginVideo" height="100%" width="100%" playsinline muted onEnded autoplay="videoEnded()">

        <source src="Delivery-B-02-End-Transparent.webm" type="video/mp4">

    </video>

</div>
<script>

    function videoEnded() {
  document.getElementById("loginVideoLayer").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
  setTimeout("videoEnded()", 5500);
  
 
</script>
<script>
      function hideHero() {
  document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  setTimeout("hideHero()", 3000);
  }
</script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.overflow = "";
    }, 2500);
  });
</script>
```

Tried researching about the website intros but no luck found.

Answer (score 0):

This example hope it helps you, after 'run code snippet' view it with the full page it should work

```js
function buildThresholdList() {
  let thresholds = [];
  let numSteps = 20;
  for (let i=1.0; i<=numSteps; i++) {
    let ratio = i/numSteps;
    thresholds.push(ratio);
  }
  thresholds.push(0);
  return thresholds;
}

function insideViewport(el, callback) {
  let observer;
  let previousRatio;
  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: buildThresholdList()
  };
  
  function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const ratio = entry.intersectionRatio;
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        if (ratio > 0.9 && previousRatio > ratio) {
          callback();
        }
        previousRatio = ratio;
      }
    })
  }
  
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  observer.observe(el);
  return observer;
}

(function () {
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  const playVideo = document.getElementById('playVideo');
  
  playVideo.addEventListener('click', function () {
    video.play();
  });;
  
  video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
  });
  
  const observer$ = insideViewport(video, function () {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    observer$.disconnect();
  });
})()
```

```css
.prefix, .postfix {
  height: 70vh;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="prefix"></div>

<video width="400" autoplay id="video">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
<button id="playVideo">play</button>

<div class="postfix"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this I'll be trying your code.

Comment: I think you got confused with my question. Here is the staging site so you can check. After the video plays the div will disappear and the hero section will appear. I just wanted to disable the scrolling while the video is playing so that they can focus on that and cannot scrub through the page.

http://thefirsttargetlimitedt3.sg-host.com/staging/